# Python Installation of chromadb failing

Tags: python, pip, python-3.11, chromadb

I tried installing chromadb but After a couple of seconds this showed up:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: hnswlib
  Building wheel for hnswlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for hnswlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'hnswlib' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]
```

I am on a windows 11H2 system and working with Py 3.11

I already installed the Build Tools and rebooting my system but it's still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chromadb official documentation says it is still not compatible with Python 3.11.
When I try to install chromadb, I do not get errors, however, I am not able to use it with vector stores and LangChain.